# 'git grep' and grep share the same options?

Tags: bash, git, grep

I have an alias in .bashrc for grep to contains grep options, e.g.,

```
alias grep='grep $GREP_OPTIONS'
```

I can't create an alias for `git grep`. What's the best way to let them share the same options?

Comment: Can you explain what steps have you followed and what it says when you source .bashrc.

Comment: Why can't you create an alias for `git grep`?

Comment: @phd because I am not sure I can have an alias with space. Moreover, calling it gg would add cognitive burden to memorize yet another alias

Comment: There is no command named `git grep`. There's a command named `git` which can take as an argument the name of an action to be performed named `grep` to do UNIX grep-like actions on files stored in git. So you could create an function named `git` to do something when called with an argument of `grep` (e.g. call `git grep  $GREP_OPTIONS`, whatever THAT does) but without a better explanation of what it is you're trying to do with sample input/output (i.e. a [mcve]) that's about all I can tell you.